# Linear Algebra (small problem)

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to count the below :

$(a^{2}I_{n} + b^{2}I_{n})^{-1}$ * $(aI_{n}  bI_{n})$ = ?

Any idea?
Note the second bracket is a matrix (1x2)
and $I_{n}$ is an identity matrix.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How come the second bracket is $1\times2$? The identity matrix, by definition, is a square matrix. So, your two bracketed terms, as well as their products, are square matrices.

Comment: I think $(aI_nbI_n)$ is meant to be $(aI_n\ bI_n)$, a matrix with $n$ rows and $2n$ columns.

Comment: I see. That makes sense, but we still need the OP to confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $a,b$ are scalars, it is just
$$\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}I_n$$

Answer (score 1):

The question is not entirely clear, but here goes. First, $$a^2I_n+b^2I_n=(a^2+b^2)I_n$$ It follows that $$(a^2I_n+b^2I_n)^{-1}=(a^2+b^2)^{-1}I_n$$ Now I'm going to assume that $(aI_nbI_n)$ is actually the $n$-by-$2n$ matrix $(aI_n\ \ bI_n)$. Then $$(a^2I_n+b^2I_n)^{-1}(aI_n\ \ bI_n)=(a^2+b^2)^{-1}I_n(aI_n\ \ bI_n)=(a^2+b^2)^{-1}(aI_n\ \ bI_n)=\left({a\over a^2+b^2}I_n\ \ {b\over a^2+b^2}I_n\right)$$